# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

i have problems setting the **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** variable running my project in a **docker container**. The problem is that the value is always **set/overwritten to "Development"**.

I have tried setting the environment variable in my **Dockerfile** using

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT test
```

also tried setting the environment variable in my **docker-compose** file using

```
environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test
```

When I set any other environment variable **it works**, for example:

```
environment:
      - OTHER_TEST_VARIABLE=test
```

I assume that the value for **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** variable is overwritten somewhere but I have difficulties finding out where.

I have added Docker support to an existing project and am running the project directly via Visual Studio's Docker/Docker compose option

The project runs on Asp Net Core 2.1

Thanks in advance

My launchSettings.json:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53183/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {

    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/api/values"
    
    }

  }
}
```

I also tried adding the environment variable configuration to the launchSettings.json

```json
"Docker": {
    "commandName": "Docker",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/api/values",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "test"
    }
}
```

My Webhost:

```cs
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
   return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext,config) =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

My docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: API/Dockerfile
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
    
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY API/API.csproj API/
RUN dotnet restore API/API.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/API
RUN dotnet build API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

Here is a list of the environment variables in the container

```
C:\Users\Administrator>docker exec -ti d6 /bin/bash
root@d6f26d2ed2c3:/app# printenv
HOSTNAME=d6f26d2ed2c3
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
test1=asdasd
test2=dasdasd
test3=dasdasd
PWD=/app
HOME=/root
NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
ASPNETCORE_VERSION=2.1.3
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
_=/usr/bin/printenv
root@d6f26d2ed2c3:/app#
```

Comment: Does this behavior only happen in docker?  If not, you may be able to set a breakpoint on `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` to see if something is invoking it.

Comment: @Matthew 

If i run outside docker, in IISExpress, the variable is set correctly, if I use following profile:

"Test": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"
      }

Comment: I guess it's VS. I'd try to start using docker-compose on command line and check env vars in container again.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It works for me by configuring `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with command `dotnet CoreDocker.dll --environment="X"`

Try to change `dockerfile` like below:

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreDocker.dll", "--environment=X"]`

Comment: It worked for me when I did this too, but I looked harder and realised that I had 2 sets of environment values set, merging them into one worked fine after that

Answer (score 36):

In the docker-compose.override.yml file, you should find something like that:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development # <==
```

Comment: Saved my life just like that. yeah.

Comment: I was crazy to find-out the issue. I never forget you, docker-compose.override.yml :) It saves my life, thx.

Answer (score 13):

## Visual Studio Docker Tooling

In case you use the Docker integration for Visual Studio (debug container from within VS) you need to pay special attention to the defaults.

#### Default Environment Variables

When the tooling is starting the debugger with a `docker run [..]` command, it supplies an `-e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development"` argument. You can overwrite this environment variable in the `Properties/launchSettings.json`.

Even though I can't see it in the issued command, in my testing I experienced another default variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80` as well.

A good starting point to read about VS Docker Tooling is [this blog post](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2019/06/18/tips-on-container-tools-for-visual-studio/) and the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019).

#### .Net-Core 3.0 Generic Host

When you use the generic host in .Net-Core 3.0 you might encounter issues when you use the new generic `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable, since you will have two environments specified then. This can be hard to debug. So what I like to do is to unset all defaults initially and start fresh in my `Properties/launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "environmentVariables": {
        // Overwrite default VS Docker Tools environment variables first (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development; ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80)
        // https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2019/06/18/tips-on-container-tools-for-visual-studio/
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "",
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
        "DOTNET_URLS": "http://+:80"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get an System.InvalidOperationException. It suggests me, that I should trust certificates, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 9):

This answer isn't stated and for me, it was the main problem. Everything I had was correct with the exception of the placement of the `ARG` and `ENV` setup in my Dockerfile.

It's important to note the position in which you define your `ARG` and `ENV` in your Dockerfile. If you do them at the top of the file, or before you build the image you need, those will get erased and not be present within your final image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

##############################
#     WON'T WORK UP HERE!    #
##############################
# ARG ENVIRONMENT
# ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .


##############################
#      WORKS DOWN HERE!      #
##############################
# Setup your variables before running.
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my.assembly.dll"]
```

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'azureContainerConnection'
    repository: 'my-repo'
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    tags: latest
    arguments: '--build-arg=ENVIRONMENT=Development'
```

code

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult HealthCheck()
{
    return Ok(_webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName);
}
```

Comment: Your argument is called ENVIRONMENT  so the correct sentence will be:   `arguments: '--build-arg=ENVIRONMENT=Development'`

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. With this solution, I can easily change the environment based on my branch.

Comment: That's solution I was looking the entire week, thanks!

Comment: Wow! What is the reason behind it?

Comment: As you add a new build stage (anytime you do `FROM ...`), it is a new build stage and environment variables aren't passed from stage to stage. I don't remember where I read it, but it was called out in their multi-stage build documentation. Just can't remember if an article pointed me to it or just found it: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/

Comment: I guess the way of oversimplifying it is that ENV only apply to the build stage they are present in. So, usually that's going to be the final build stage depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Very stupid mistake I made.

I have VS 2019 and I added Docker support to my project. So, I have a `Dockerfile` for my WebApi and a `docker-compose` file.

Basically, I tried everything that you guys said above but nothing worked for me.

What I found out is that there was a docker-compose.override.yml which was setting these env varibales. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your comments, I solved my issue. It was just my mistake.

My problem was that when I added Docker-Support to my project I already had a Dockerfile included in the project.

When VS generated files for Docker-support, there was a second Dockerfile created, and one of the Dockerfiles was renamed to "Dockerfile.original".

I was using the "Dockerfile" visible in the solution explorer (which was somehow mapped to the "Dockerfile.original" file in the filesystem)

It seems that in the background my changes where written to "Dockerfile.original" but this file wasn't used while docker-compose was running. It used the empty generated Dockerfile that wasn't visible in the Solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I use Rider, I had the environment variable only on the docker-compose file in the service environment section.

What was happening on my end was I did not have ***ConnectionStrings*** set in my `appsettings.Development.json` so it defaulted to the `appsettings.json` file's ***ConnectionStrings***.

I after adding the proper connection string to the development json file everything worked fine with the docker-compose up command. Hope this helps someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

For who work with linux container:

`ENTRYPOINT export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development && exec dotnet "app.dll"`

Answer (score 0):

Doing `docker compose down` does not actually do anything to the docker images in `docker images`, which is what pops back again when you do `docker compose up -d`.

You may have to do `docker rmi imageName` and then do `docker compose up -d` for the image to build again.

Now, setting `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development` or say `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://0.0.0.0:6000"` in the **Dockerfile**  should work fine when you do `docker compose up -d` again.

**PS** - You should see logs like below when you run `docker compose up -d` meaning the image is being built.

```
[+] Building 12.9s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 634B                                                          0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.0                         0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 164.84kB                                                         0.1s
 => [app build-env 1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [app build-env 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                   0.0s
 => [app build-env 3/5] COPY . ./                                                             0.2s
 => [app build-env 4/5] RUN dotnet restore Strange/*.csproj                                8.7s
 => [app build-env 5/5] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out PerfRunner/*.csproj              3.7s
 => CACHED [app stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build-str-env /app/out .                                 0.0s 
 => [app] exporting to image                                                                  0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                       0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:a14415b5a8738fb8e28333f23c550370662d4503d1cf7008fc2b7c0469cb09bb  0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/str-app                                             0.0s 
[+] Running 2/2                                                                                    
 ✔ Network str_default  Created                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container str-app-srvc     Started
```