# How to set the environment in a docker with Visual Studio 2019 in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, docker-desktop

struggling in Visual Studio 2019 in ASP.NET Core 3.1 (Win10 with Docker Desktop).
I only want to change the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" from "Development" to "Production.

So what I've done was then to edit
**launchSettings.json**

and edit the environment variables section:

```
"profiles": {

   ///cut other

   "Docker": {
        "commandName": "Docker",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/version",
        "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
           },

        "publishAllPorts": true,
        "useSSL": false
   }
 }
```

When I then start debugging in Visual Studio I get: "*Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint*",
unless it is working fine with "Development".
Nevertheless the container shows in *docker inspect* still the "Development"

[image]

When I then add `"ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://+:80"`
the container starts but still shows ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development. Also inside the docker when executing "ENV".

Don't really know, what else I can try.

Hope on your guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a UI Bug, you can check by

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

In my case, the application shows "Production",
but Visual Studio container debug tool shows "Developement".
Besides, you can add a "appsetting.Production.json" to double check the config is changing to Production, hope it helps.

Comment: Unbelievable! It was a UI bug for me too. I created an endpoint that returns the environment using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"); and it works as expected. It returns the value set in launchSettings.json. This is using Visual Studio 2022 Community 17.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this question helpful: [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376855/aspnetcore-environment-in-docker/52383707)

The proposed solution there - specify the environment in Dockerfile`s ENTRYPOINT:
`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreDocker.dll", "--environment=Production"]`

Comment: Yes, thanks I've already walked through this thread and tested everything. Not worked for me. Its also contains docker compose, I'm not using here and is core 2.x