# .Net 6 Docker ENV is not set

Tags: docker, environment-variables, containers, .net-6.0

I have following docker file where I set some default value to an environment variable.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG environment_arg=Debug
ENV environment_env=$environment_arg

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation/PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.csproj", "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation/"]
COPY ["PreAdviceGeneration.Application/PreAdviceGeneration.Application.csproj", "PreAdviceGeneration.Application/"]
COPY ["PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure/PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure.csproj", "PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation/PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation"

RUN dotnet build "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

RUN echo "The set environment $environment_env"
RUN echo "The set Argument is $environment_arg"

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.dll"]
```

I build the image with following command:

```
docker build --build-arg environment_arg=Test -t pag .
```

I ran the container with command:

```
docker run --name pag pag
```

I cannot see the environment variable `environment_env` in the container. I would imagine that when I set default value to the environment variable in the build stage, it would be available even when I don't pass one with `-e` parameter during the run stage.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answer by @mwilson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490269/8556538). The position of the environment variable declaration matters. We need to set it after we copy the published artifacts into the `/app` directory.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think environment variables set in the Docker file only exist during image creation. To actually set the value when running a container, use docker run with a -e flag for each environment variable

Comment: I think, you are talking about ARG variables. Checkout this [blog](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/). 
> you can also provide default ENV values directly in your Dockerfile by hard-coding them